# Applying filter on an RDD of Vectors/Array[Double]

Tags: arrays, scala, vector, apache-spark, rdd

Suppose I have an RDD of Array[Double], with n columns. I want to apply a filter on the last column (say, the value > some constant).

- What is the syntax for this in Scala/Apache Spark?
- Is it possible to do the same if I had an RDD of Vectors?
- If I can choose one over the other (i.e., RDD of Array[Double] and RDD of Vectors), which one should I choose in order to have more
  efficient/faster code?

Answer (score 2):

Something like that

```
val rdd: RDD[Array[Double]] = ...
val filtered: RDD[Array[Double]] = rdd.filter(arr => arr.last() > some_value)
```

I don't think that it really matter what to choose Array or Vector. Overall overhead of Spark is much-much higher than performance/memory benefits from Arrays vs Vectors